# coursor interactive 360 video/image background in html5 bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

title says it all. I am looking to have 360 video or a 360 image as background of my html5 website developed using bootstrap. and the video/image should move based on cursor position. i searched for a fair amount of time but could not find anything.
If anyone knows any source where i can learn this please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with a slight modification to [aframe.io](https://aframe.io/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/nleoutsa/auto-follow-aframe/master/dist/aframe-master.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <video id="paris" autoplay loop="true" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/hapyak_demos/css360/videos/paris360.mp4">
      </a-assets>
      <a-videosphere src="#paris"></a-videosphere>
    </a-scene>
  </body>

</html>
```

[Demo on JsBin](http://jsbin.com/juyeyavayu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

You can setup the scene using either 'a-sky' or 'a-videosphere' ([aframe videosphere documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/primitives/a-videosphere.html)) and enable look-controls (see docs). Default Aframe behavior will allow a user to click and drag to rotate the scene.

If you fork the Aframe repo and modify the [look-controls.js file](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/look-controls.js#L252) you can make it follow the cursor without holding the mouse down.

I've forked aframe and made the changes here if you want to see the diff: https://github.com/nleoutsa/auto-follow-aframe. It's a very small change.

Hope this helps!
-Nick Leoutsakos